# What format does the datastore admin backup the entities in?

Tags: google-app-engine, backup, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups, blobstore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [options for restoring appengine datastore data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420007/options-for-restoring-appengine-datastore-data)

I'd like to parse the files the datastore admin produces during the backup process.

I backup entities to the blobstore. I'd like to selectively extract some of the data from blobstore backup entities and need to be able to open the file and inspect the entities.

What format are these files stored in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [datastore admin source code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/backup_handler.py): backup file are stored in [leveldb log format](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/log_format.txt).

Comment: Thanks. Also found that you can use RecordReadChannel and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/EntityTranslator to go from the blob items to actual entities in Java.

Comment: That link is broken, here's the new one: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/datastore_admin/backup_handler.py