# Restoring Google App Engine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, restore, database-backups

I am trying to implement in Java what we discussed here:
[options for restoring appengine datastore data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420007/options-for-restoring-appengine-datastore-data)

.. but I have some problems. Here is my code:
https://github.com/micheleorsi/manage-gae-backup/blob/master/src/test/java/com/map2app/manage/test/ReadFileTest.java
.. and I get this error:
com.google.appengine.api.files.RecordReadChannelImpl readRecord WARNING: Checksum doesn't validate
when it runs this row:

```
ByteBuffer bf = rrc.readRecord();
```

The file I am trying to restore is:
120424.060000_production.sql3
and it is backed-up with the system explained here:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data
(raw format, no special configuration set)

Comment: probably it is in a compressed form? ..

Answer (score 0):

The method described in [options for restoring appengine datastore data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420007/options-for-restoring-appengine-datastore-data) is for the files created using the [backup and restore tool accessible in the admin console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin).

The [command line tools](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Downloading_and_Uploading_All_Data) shipped with the SDK uses a different format (sqlite).

Comment: ah ok thank you! I am using java, that's why .. I remember I tried with sqlite but I had still problems